# Modular Math - Easy approach (Fermat's ?)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I Know How to solve 5^31 mod 133 using Modular exponentiation, but I am wondering if there is a quicker way to solve this problem - like Fermat's Little theorem

I won't have access to a calculator in the exam. So, I want to solve this quickly and accurately. Thanks for your help

Comment: This question is not about software development and therefore is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fermat's little theorem to solve this problem quickly and accurately, and you could also use modular exponentiation to solve this problem quickly and accurately.

For example, to solve 5^31 mod 133, you could use the following steps:

1. Use modular exponentiation to calculate 5^30 mod 133. This can be done by repeatedly squaring 5 and taking the remainder each time until you reach 30.
2. Use modular exponentiation to calculate 5^1 mod 133. This can be done by repeatedly squaring 5 and taking the remainder each time until you reach 1.
3. Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine the results from steps 1 and 2 to get the final answer.